# Converting truetype glyphs to OpenGL polygons

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, truetype

I am trying to create a conversion library for any installed truetype font into a series of polygons that can be used to display text in OpenGL. I use the GetGlyphOutline function to convert glyphs into a series of contours then triangulate (tesselate) these contours with the glu library.

It usually works but not always and there are weird exceptions. GetGlyphOutline is supposed to return outer contours first in a CW winding order and inner contours (holes) in CCW winding order. Depending on the font and the glyph, this is not the case unfortunately. Sometimes the outer contour is in a CCW winding order and holes are in CW, or although the winding order is correct, the order of contours returned by GetGlyphOutline is wrong (e.g. I get the 'holes' first then the outer contour).

I tried to adjust the conversion to check for these weird cases and if necessary reverse the vertices and winding order of a contour but seemingly there is no rule and if a character with 1 or 2 holes in it is OK with a few fonts, I always find an exception. E.g. with a font named MinionPro-BoldCn even the glyph for the number '8' is returned by GetGlyphOutline wrong and I end up with only one hole inside instead of two.

I also tried to use another method instead of GetGlyphOutline. I use GDI to render text into a path, then get the contours of that path using the GetPath function. The result is the same. There are fonts where certain characters are returned by GetPath with the wrong order of contours and/or with the wrong winding.

Does anyone have any experience with this and is there anything I can do?

Comment: You could probably assume that the outer-most region is "empty" and then alternate between filling and not filling closed-off regions. This will break down with self-intersecting shapes though.

Comment: Probably your idea would work most of the time, I had a few similar myself, but not all the time. For some reason, when I draw characters (TextOut) as part of a path, then read back this path using GetPath, in case of some of the fonts contours are returned correctly (i.e. outers first with cw winding, then inners with ccw winding), but with other fonts contours are returned in no particular order and their winding can be wrong.

Comment: The winding doesn't have any impact on what I'm suggesting tho. Why would it not work?

Comment: Because you cannot be sure what contours form which parts of a glyph. If a smaller contour is totally inside of a bigger one than it is a hole, but there are some exotic languages where contours can overlap and there are more than one outer contour in a glyph.

Comment: This is an old topic, but I want to know how to solved this issue. I'm considering similar approach for my OpenGL game. I did not anything yet but in my opinion, parsing TTF or OTF is better instead of `GetGlyphOutline()`. If you online, please call me back!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a perfect workaround, but one idea (haven't thought of any counterexamples):

1. Ignore the winding order
2. Draw all glyphs into the stencil buffer, incrementing the stencil value by 1 each time a fragment is drawn.
3. Draw a quad over the scene, filling in any pixel where the stencil buffer == 1.

My thinking is that any area not covered by the glyph will have stencil value == 0, any area inside the glyph will have a stencil value == 1, and any holes inside the glyph will have a stencil value == 2 (as they are covered by the original glyph and the "hole"). You can then filter by this to only draw areas where the stencil is equal to 1.

Comment: Sorry, that would not work in my case. I need the polygons (triangles) to create 3D objects from glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a rule to determine wether a contour delimits an outer or inner region of the glyph.
For each edge in an inner contour,there must be at least one point such that the triangle is in a clockwise winding order.
For an edge in an outer contour,there must be no point such that the triangle is in a clockwise winding order.
see the Outlines section in [TrueType fundamentals](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/ttf_spec/ttch01.doc).

Comment: The link is dead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttch01#outlines The doc said, **the black space (the filled area) will always be to the right.** It means that the contour always clockwise winding.